# VBA Format cell fill color based on content file type

Tags: vba, excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to read a list of documents in a column of Excel and depending the type of file change the color of the cell. but I can't do it. Any solutions?

```
Public Sub Master()

       Dim TdCel As Range, FCell As Range

       Set TdCel = Range("A1:A25")

       For Each FCell In TdCel

          If FCell.Text = "*.pdf" Then
                FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            ElseIf FCell.Value = "*.*.doc" Then
                FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
            ElseIf FCell.Value = "*.jpg" Then
                FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            Else
                FCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
          End If
       Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? what is causing the issue? As an initial recommendation i'd recommend using instr, and sticking to .value (this is the default property so is redundant to state). Usage would be if instr(1,fcell,".pdf") > 0 then

Comment: Why don't you just use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-FED60DFA-1D3F-4E13-9ECB-F1951FF89D7F)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few improvements :

1. Define the sheet in which you work (change  *Sheet's name* in the line `Set wS = ...`
2. Use of `With`
3. Use of `Select Case` and `Like`, on the lowered case cell's value (`LCase()`)

Working solution :

```
Public Sub Master_JoaoTS()
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim TdCel As Range, FCell As Range, CellVal As String
    Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet's Name")
    Set TdCel = wS.Range("A1:A25")

    For Each FCell In TdCel
        With FCell
            CellVal = LCase(.Value)
            With .Interior
                Select Case True
                    Case CellVal Like "*.pdf"
                        .ColorIndex = 10
                    Case CellVal Like "*.doc*"
                        .ColorIndex = 9
                    Case CellVal Like "*.jpg"
                        .ColorIndex = 8
                    Case Else
                        .Pattern = xlNone
                End Select
            End With '.Interior
        End With 'FCell
    Next FCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

little **edit** to shorten down the code (and make @R3uK more undesirable...)

you coudl use [`Switch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264257(v=office.15).aspx) function

```
Public Sub Master_JoaoTS()
    Dim FCell As Range
    Dim docType As String
    Dim clrIndex As Variant

    For Each FCell In Worksheets("myWorksheetName").Range("A1:A25").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        With FCell
            docType = LCase(Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - InStrRev(.Value, ".")))
            clrIndex = Switch(docType = "pdf", 10, _
                             docType = "doc", 9, _
                             docType = "jpg", 8)
            If IsNull(clrIndex) Then clrIndex = 2
            .Interior.ColorIndex = clrIndex
        End With
    Next FCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! I've never saw that, might be handy sometimes! :)

Comment: @R3uK, edited to make it even nicer and ... hoping you appreciate it!

Comment: I love it! :) But I can't upvote it more! BTW, if have you some notions in Word (not VBA though...) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116944/calculation-fields-not-working-with-dates

Comment: @R3uK, I'll have a look as soon as possible. Not promising any result though

Comment: No worries, it ain't that urgent but I hate word, especially when things should be working and yet they are quite painful!^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution not too far from your original code, using the InStr function to find the substrings ".pdf", ".doc", and ".jpg".

```
Public Sub Master()

  Dim TdCel As Range, FCell As Range

  Set TdCel = Range("A1:A25")

  For Each FCell In TdCel

    If InStr(FCell, ".pdf") Then
      FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    ElseIf InStr(FCell, ".doc") Then
      FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
    ElseIf InStr(FCell, ".jpg") Then
      FCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Else
      FCell.Interior.Color = vbWhite
    End If

  Next

End Sub
```